# Marshalling datatype issue

Tags: c#

Below is the code which I am trying to convert from c++ into c#

```
struct PSB {
   short    type_of_psb;
   short    call_dependent;
   int32    del_psb_status;
   uint32   seq_number[2];
   int32    uma_psb_status;
   short    psb_reserved[6];
}
```

Previously, I wrote below structure.

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct PSB
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public short type_of_psb;
            [FieldOffset(2)]
            public short call_dependent;
            [FieldOffset(4)]
            public int del_psb_status;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
            public uint32 seq_number; // Here is the problem
            [FieldOffset(16)]
            public int uma_psb_status;
            [FieldOffset(20)]
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
            public short[] psb_reserved;
        }
```

but above c# code does not work, problem is in member **seq_number**

So i changed it into

`public ulong seq_number` from `uint seq_number`, and I removed above marshalas attribute.

Now it is working with legacy code. I don't know why ? What is the problem if I defined like as array ?

Comment: i dont see that `seq_number` is an array.

Comment: shouldn't it be `public uint32[] seq_number`, I'm guessing the ulong works because it would be stored as two sequential ints but you might have an LSB issue...

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ struct and your `MarshalAs` attribute both listed the type as an array, but your C# struct was only declaring a number. I'm not sure exactly what error you were getting, but it looks like you were trying to convert an array of two numbers into a single number, which obviously would cause some issues.

Try keeping `MarshalAs` attribute as-is in your posted struct and simply replace `public uint32 seq_number;` with `public uint32[] seq_number;`.

Comment: i applied  public uint32[] seq_number; , but problem remains the same

Comment: @kamal: Please edit your post with the exact error you're getting and the code that's generating that error.